# Turkey stock abandoned half way Monday room temp still safe?

Tags: stock, turkey

I started making stock by boiling the turkey carcass, this was for my African pepper soup.
It had been cooking for about an hour and then I was taken ill and had to turn it off so I could go to bed.It was in a pressure cooker and I sealed the lid on ,this was on Monday and it has been sitting at room temperature is it safe to carry on using it?

Comment: Sorry, but no. We have a [generic post](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat) that explains the finer details, but even in a sealed pot, two days is way beyond safe. Sorry if we close your first question, nothing personal., it's just a kind of question we get very often. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Let me suggets you take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: When in doubt, throw it out!

Comment: *this was on Monday* is a useless remark as this question gets older